# Read data from a balance via RS232 port using rs232 to usb converter cable in rapsberry pi

Tags: gpio, python, communication, data-transfer

I am a beginner to this,

I have a balance (scale) that I need to read the data (weights of material) from. Data will be read every 10 seconds and I have looked up RS232 codes in here and utilised below code.

I have connected the balance (scale) to the Pi using a serial to USB cable

```
import serial

port =serial.Serial(

   "/dev/ttyUSB0",
   baudrate=9600,
   parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
   stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
   bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
   writeTimeout = 0,
   timeout = 10)

print(port.isOpen()) 
print(port.readable())
print(port.get_settings())
while True:


 response=port.read(8)
 print(response)
```

but as the output all I`m getting is
    b''

in the balance manual I have below information,

```
 INTERFACE 
 RS232 Connection             
 Balance (9pins)             PC(9 pins)
 RXD(Input)  2 -----------------3
 TXD(Output) 3 -----------------2
 GND(Ground) 5 -----------------5

 Default Baudrate 9600
 Data format 10bits,0 as start bit,1as stop bit,8digits (ASCII code)
 Ritybit, No.
```

Thanks in advance you all.

[image]

Comment: Could you edit the question and add a link to the interface specs of the balance?  We need details of how it is controlled and what it returns.

Comment: Do you have the crossover in place, as indicated by the connection diagram from the manual? (Pin 2-3, 3-2.) The manual also indicates 10 bits - which I don't understand as it indicates there are 8 data bits, 1 stop and no start or parity, so that makes 9. You might do well to connect the USB adapter to a PC and fiddle around to find the right combination of settings and wiring using a terminal program, then transfer to code when you have it working.

Comment: @joan I have added the specs from the balance

Comment: Also, do you know what format you expect the data in? Your code sort of assumes it will be printable characters - maybe that's a reasonable assumption, I don't know. Do you have to send anything to get a response or will the device just send data all the time, unprompted? Again a terminal program would let you experiment.

Comment: @MarkSmith 10 bits per byte is pretty normal. 1 start, 8 data, 1 stop.

Comment: @MarkSmith It says start bit low (0), 8 data bits, stop bit high (1).  Which is pretty normal.

Comment: @joan I beg your pardon, I had interpreted that as "no start bits".

Comment: @DrakonianD - the specs you have uploaded do not match those elsewhere in your question -- for example is default baud 2400 or 9600?

Comment: Your spec indicates the scale "defaults" to 2400 but can be changed.  I see your code expects 9600.  Did you reconfigure the scale to 2400 (also is this change preserved if you power the scale off & back on?)  Apart from that, I'm curious if the serial cable is wired with the cross-over (pins 2 & 3 swapped -- as Mark already inquired about above).  It's possible to pick up a very inexpensive "null modem adapter" which handles the pin swap (and some models also serve as a gender changer since DTE pins are normal "male" DB9 adapters.)

Comment: @MarkSmith Hi Mark I am now using a null modem RS232 cable from the balance and the RS232 to USB converter to get the data

Comment: @MarkSmith getting the null modem cable fixed the issue and I changed the print bits to 16 and that fixed the issue. thank you Mark